# Asp.Net core AddJwtBearer default caching of JWKS?

Tags: authentication, caching, .net-core, jwt, openid-connect

I have configured the AddJwtBearer with basic settings and the authority is an OpenID-connect identity server. It is working fine but what is the default caching implementation of the JWKS URL, its timeout, and how to configure the caching timeout?

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"];
    options.Audience = Configuration["Audience"];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you ask asking for the caching duration.

The class that is in charge of the caching of the JWKS data is the ConfigurationManager class and You can find the source code for the class [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs).

The default caching time is 24 hours.

To set it in your API, you can control it in .NET 5 using code similar to the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
      ...

      //set refresh interval to 1 hour
      opt.AutomaticRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
    });
```

Before .NET 5 this was readonly, but they made it editable in .NET 5.